# How to configure my TP-Link Archer C9 router as an access point?

Tags: wireless-router, home-networking, wireless-access-point

My ISP already provides a modem-router hardware, so I need to configure my Archer C9 as an access point.

So

- I do not use the WAN port: I plugged my ISP router in a 1GB LAN port;
- I disabled the DHCP server on the Archer;
- I set a static IP address with the correct subnet mask and gateway.

Despite everything is working fine, I am unable to log on the Archer admin page. Furthermore, the Archer does not appear as connected to my ISP router admin page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortly -

1. assign a unique static IP to the router's LAN interface so it won't overlap with the main router/gateway or it's DHCP pool. To avoid address conflicts make a static DHCP provisioning on the main router DHCP for the C9's new LAN address, e.g. 192.168.0.254
2. disable C9's DHCP
3. connect C9 via LAN but not WAN port

Courtesy / screenshots https://awesometoast.com/archer-c9/

Comment: That is exactly what I did and it worked fine. Thanks a lot for your answer!